# Powershell Multi-part-form-data convert from curl

Tags: powershell, curl

I'm trying to run a powershell script to perform an invoke-webrequest using the -ContentType multi-part/form-data parameter.

I have an example of a working curl command and need to convert it to powershell.

```
curl -v -u user@yourcompany.com:test -F "helpdesk_ticket[attachments][][resource]=@/path/to/attachment1.ext" -F "helpdesk_ticket[attachments][][resource]=@/path/to/attachment2.ext" -F "helpdesk_ticket[email]=example@example.com" -F "helpdesk_ticket[subject]=Ticket Title" -F "helpdesk_ticket[description]=this is a sample ticket" -X POST https://domain.webaddress.com/helpdesk/tickets.json
```

I have tried to do this with hash tables but having no luck.

So far I have:

```
$body = @{"helpdesk_ticket[attachments][][resource]"="$/path/to/attachment.ext";"helpdesk_ticket[email]"="example@example.com"; "helpdesk_ticket[subject]"="Ticket Title"; "helpdesk_ticket[description]"="this is a sample ticket"}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://domain.webaddress.com/helpdesk/tickets.json -Headers $FSHeaders -ContentType multi-part/form-data -Body $Body  -Method POST
```

The error returned suggests the data in the body is incorrect as authentication (hidden in the header variable) is correct.

Comment: if the error is authentication then what does $FSHeaders look like?  You'll proabably have to use convertto-json and even possible with the -compress parameter if the object is multi-dimensional.

Comment: the body is totally off

Comment: The body is irrelevant (at least at this point) if the error is authentication.  Is the authentication error related to web server auth or API auth?  If it's web server auth then you need to use the credentials parameter of the Invoke-Webrequest cmdlet.  If it's API auth then you need to look up the helpdesk software API to see how they want the authentication presented to the API so it can be structured appropriately.

Comment: can you post a query response so i can see a sample of the post

Comment: My $FSHeaders currently looks like
`Name  : Authorization
Value : Basic Y2hyaXMuZGV2cmVsbEBpdGVjaC1zZXJ2aWNlcy5jby51azpQYXNzd29yZDE=`
Using a purposely incorrect password I get the following response:
_StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"require_login":true}_
So I'm pretty confident this must be the body causing the error.

Unfortunately, the web app does not give much in response as I receive the following error:
**Invoke-WebRequest : We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.**